# Prolog разбить список на N подсписков

Tags: list, prolog

Помогите с реализацией, нужно разбить список на N подсписков(частей), записывая в эти подсписки элементы поочередно.
То есть, нужно задать список чисел , например, [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7] и N, например, N=2.
Res = [[0,1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]

Получилось сделать чтобы было по N элементов в каждом подсписке, но как разбить список на N частей не могу понять....

Comment: Вы бы язык указали....

Comment: Так указан язык.... Prolog